# Why isn't CakePHP using SQL joins

Tags: cakephp, join, containable

I'm fairly new to CakePHP, and have run into an issue that I can't seem to find a good solution for.  My application has the following associations:

- Member hasMany Vote
- Roll hasMany Vote
- Vote belongsTo Member, Roll

I'd like to retrieve all of the votes cast by a member and the roll associated with each vote.  The following code produces the perfect result:

```
$this->Member->id = $id;
$this->Member->contain(array('Vote' => 'Roll'));
$this->set('member_data', $this->Member->read());
```

Unfortunately, this code is also very inefficient.  Instead of just doing something like `SELECT * FROM votes JOIN rolls ON votes.roll_id = rolls.id WHERE votes.member_id = 100`, Cake does the following:

1. `SELECT * FROM votes WHERE member_id = 100`
2. `SELECT * FROM rolls WHERE roll_id = 1`
3. `SELECT * FROM rolls WHERE roll_id = 2`
4. `SELECT * FROM rolls WHERE roll_id = 3`
5. `SELECT * FROM rolls WHERE roll_id = 4`
6. And so on--a big problem when over 500 rolls match!

How would I make this more efficient while still using the read() method?

Comment: Have you specified the model relationship?

Comment: Yes.  In each of the three models I specified the associations from the bullet list above.

Comment: It may also be notable that this issue exists even when the relationship between Roll and Vote is changed to `Roll hasOne Vote`.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containablebehavior-options . This might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try from vote model, try this code:

```
$this->Vote->recursive = 0;
$this->Vote->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Vote.member_id'=>100)));
```

Comment: That works just fine, but I'm more interested in **why** my previous attempt was so inefficient.  Call it a teaching opportunity.

Comment: you want to fetch data from votes table as per your query and trying to access with member table that makes it more complicated so if you want to fetch data from any table try with same model, relationship will populate automatically